# Detect headset button press

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I need to utilize the headset button press for something other than multimedia on my app.  Here's what I have so far and it's not working.  When I press the headset button, my app does not respond, instead music plays...

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {

return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
if ([self canBecomeFirstResponder]) {
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"became first responder");
}

}

 - (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)theEvent
 {
if (theEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {
    switch(theEvent.subtype) {
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
            NSLog(@"Hello");

        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
            NSLog(@"Hello 2");
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
            NSLog(@"Hello 3");
            break;
        case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop:
            NSLog(@"Hello 4");
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

@user1724494 the code you have used works only when app running in background, since the event is an remote event we can only handle in background operation.

Please refer to the Apple document http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: This is false.  However, the app must have "Now Playing" status, which can only be reached by playing some form of audio.